# jQuery.css(), what unit are those position/size-values?

Tags: jquery

i very often see code like this:

```
    jQuery('#aslkdjf').css({top:2+'px'});
```

can i get rid of the:

```
 +'px'
```

? Or do i have to configure the default unit of those values?

Any official documentations?

**Even the Community isnt sure in this case**: The first comment of the user "piki" on the page http://api.jquery.com/css/ suggest that sometimes mm are used, sometimes px are used.
Piki's question even have 55 upvote's (my post isnt a try to get upvoted too 8D)

Comment: I like to get sure that noone can override the missing +'px' by setting a default-unit via jquery configuration.

Comment: @PeterRader For such questions, I recommend to look in the source code of jQuery, either at [Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery), or James' jQuery source viewer. Examine this piece of code: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.style

Comment: @RobW +1  can you define this as a answer? i will accept this as right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rob W wrote,

a look on the sourcecode (http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.style) is the solution.

Scott Evernden and jamis0n are right too.

Answer (score 2):

> css({top: 2})

works as you'd expect; 'px' by default

Comment: sometimes mm are returned.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure the default type, if you pass say just an integer, is 'px' ... I have also successfully applied others, such as '50%' etc...

```
$('#aslkdjf').css({width:'50%'}); //Set to 50%
$('#aslkdjf').css({width:5}); //Set to 5 px
```